# How can you navigate the metro and bus in Belarus on your smartphone?

Tags: public-transport, maps, belarus, minsk

While traveling to foreign countries I always use Google Map (except in China and South Korea where I use Baidu and Naver Map). One of the best feature on Google Map is if you select any place and tap on *"show the route"*, it automatically displays the different ways of getting to the place, including walking, public transport, and taxi.

However in Minsk, even though you pick up a place and choose *"show the route"*, it doesn't include the public transportation route. So I must look for any metro station located near the destination on Google Map, and any metro station near where I'm now as well, and then [open a metro map image](http://www.belarus.by/rel_image/3726) to get to know how to reach the place. This is quite a painstaking process.

So is there any better way to know which metro and bus to take, possibly on another app (or how do locals search for it...?)? I'm looking for a way to type in the origin and the destination and know which station I should go to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use [Yandex Maps](https://yandex.com/maps/) app. They should have routing in Belarus.

They also have [Yandex Metro](https://metro.yandex.com/minsk), but given that Minsk still has just two lines it's not a dire necessity.

They have [map](https://mobile.yandex.ru/apps/android/maps/#main) and [metro](https://mobile.yandex.ru/apps/android/metro#main) apps for popular mobile platforms - the landing page is in Russian but store buttons should be self-explainatory.

Comment: Thanks. The map app looks much better than Google Map, but I just found that the station name is sometimes quite different between Russian and Belarusian, and this map works sometimes poorly if you search in Belarusian. But the metro route is always displayed on the map with the vivid color, and it exactly meets my needs!